# How do I get an array of users in a specifc voice channel?

Tags: api, discord

I am using the HTTP API for Discord and I need to get the users in a specific voice channel. What endpoint is used for this?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please let us know first which Coding Language you want to use.

Comment: @Twenty They presumably just want the endpoint, so it's not language dependant

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't possible.

Voice state update events are fired via the Discord WebSockets and there aren't any equivalent API endpoints available.